# ruby - access array with hash key

Tags: ruby

I am struggling to understand how I can access an array with a hash key. In my code, I create a hash with keys and values. Now, I want to set the values in a `Car` class. Whenever I try to instantiate the Car, the argument expects Integer and not a String.

I am getting the following error: `TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`

Here is my code:

```
class Car_maker

 attr_accessor :car_maker

 def initialize(car_maker)
  @car_maker = car_maker
 end

end

class Car_model < Car_maker

attr_accessor :km, :type, :transmission, :stock, :drivetrain, :status, 
:fuel, :car_maker, :model, :year, :trim, :features
#total number of instances & array with car objects
@@totalCars = 0
@@catalogue = []

def initialize(km, type, transmission, stock, drivetrain, status, fuel, car_maker, model, year, trim, features)
    super(car_maker)
    @km = km
    @type = type
    @transmission = transmission
    @stock = stock
    @drivetrain = drivetrain
    @status = status
    @fuel = fuel
    @model = model
    @year = year
    @trim = trim
    @features = features
    @@totalCars += 1
end 

def self.convertListings2Catalogue(line)
    #Initialise arrays and use them to compare
    type = ["Sedan", "coupe", "hatchback", "station", "SUV"]
    transmission = ["auto", "manual", "steptronic"]
    drivetrain = ["FWD", "RWD", "AWD"]
    status = ["new", "used"]
    car_maker = ["honda", "toyota", "mercedes", "bmw", "lexus"]
    hash = Hash.new

    #In this part, we hash the set of features using regex
    copyOfLine = line
    regex = Regexp.new(/{(.*?)}/)
    match_array = copyOfLine.scan(regex)

    match_array.each do |line|
        hash["features"] = line
    end

    #Now, we split every comma and start matching fields
    newStr = line[0...line.index('{')] + line[line.index('}')+1...line.length]
    arrayOfElements = newStr.split(',')

    arrayOfElements.each do |value|
        if value.include?("km") and !value.include?("/")
            hash["km"] = value
        elsif type.include?(value)
            hash["type"] = value
        elsif transmission.include?(value.downcase)
            hash["transmission"] = value
        elsif value.include?("/") and value.include?("km")
            hash["fuel economy"] = value
        elsif drivetrain.include?(value)
            hash["drivetrain"] = value
        elsif status.include?(value.downcase)
            hash["status"] = value
        elsif /(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/.match(value) and !value.include?("km")
            hash["stock"] = value
        elsif car_maker.include?(value.downcase)
            hash["carmaker"] = value
        elsif /^\d{4}$/.match(value)
            hash["year"] = value
        elsif value.length == 2
            hash["trim"] = value
        else
            if value.length > 2
                hash["model"] = value
            end
        end 
    end 
  end
 end

 textFile = File.open('cars.txt', 'r')
 textFile.each_line{|line|
   if line.length > 2
    result = Car_model.convertListings2Catalogue(line)
    puts "Hash: #{result}"

    carObj = Car_model.new(result["km"], result["type"], result["transmission"], result["stock"], result["drivetrain"],
    result["status"], result["fuel"], result["carmaker"], result["model"], result["year"], result["trim"], result["features"])
    #@@catalogue.push (carObj)
end
}
```

Comment: What's the array, you're trying to access with a hash key? what's the key?

Comment: In the last lines, I am trying to create a car by calling `Car_model.new(result["type"]....)`

Comment: `"type"` is the key, but it expects an Integer since `result` is an array. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, but, what's the content of `result`?, as an example. Expected input, expected output.

Comment: `result` is a hash table with the following : `{"features"=>["AC,Heated Seats,Heated Mirrors,Keyless Entry"], "km"=>"65101km", "type"=>"Sedan", "transmission"=>"Manual", "stock"=>"18131A", "drivetrain"=>"FWD", "status"=>"Used", "fuel economy"=>"5.5L/100km", "carmaker"=>"Toyota", "model"=>"camry", "trim"=>"SE", "year"=>"2010"}`

Comment: Doesn't `{"features"=>["AC,Heated Seats,Heated Mirrors,Keyless Entry"], "km"=>"65101km", "type"=>"Sedan", "transmission"=>"Manual", "stock"=>"18131A", "drivetrain"=>"FWD", "status"=>"Used", "fuel economy"=>"5.5L/100km", "carmaker"=>"Toyota", "model"=>"camry", "trim"=>"SE", "year"=>"2010"}['type'] # => "Sedan"` work for you?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: I think it simply means that one of the values you are trying to pass into the new object is expecting an integer and is instead getting a string. Probably one of your numeric values. It would help if you showed more of the error code, i.e. the line the error code references.

Comment: Also add at least two lines of the file you are opening so that we can test using your actual values. We need to see the exact format of the data you are importing.

Comment: classes should be camel cased not underscored

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
result = Car_model.convertListings2Catalogue(line)
```

Doesn't return the `hash` object. It returns `arrayOfElements` since that's what the `each` method actually returns and the `each` method is the last method executed in the method (although there are hash assignments within it, it's only the last value that's returned unless you use an explicit `return` statement.

Just use the variable `hash` in the last line of the `convertListing2Catalog` method

```
        if value.length > 2
          hash["model"] = value
        end
      end 
    end 
    hash # < this is the last line of the method so it's the value that will be returned
  end
end
```

If you think about it, there were several variables created in the method.  There's no reason to expect that the contents of any specific variable such as `hash` would be returned, and ruby methods by default return the last executed command.